# Double integral properties used in theorem?

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, expected-value, multiple-integral

Ok this question is a about integral properties used to proof a theorem (a Expectation value for random variables theorem). 
My question is only about calculation of what properties it used for double integrals. 
The two photos show the complete theorem and its proof. 
The photo in part2 with a arrow shows where the calculations are performed.

[Expectation Theorem : part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziiCy.jpg) 
 [Expectation Theorem : part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wVHj.jpg)

In the photo n.r.v means continuous random variable  
and n.r.d means discrete random variable

 
$f_{Y}$ is a density for the continuous random variable Y:

$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \  [\int_{y}^{\infty} f_Y(x)dx ] \ dy $ 
= $ \int_{0}^{\infty} \  [\int_{0}^{x} dy ] \ \ f_Y(x) dx $ 

 How are the calculations made for this part (What properties are used )? 
 If you need any help about the text comment down.

Comment: I just spent about 45 minutes trying to crack this.  I am out of my depth here.

Comment: Thank you for trying.

Comment: it seems the problem i want is in here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2060296/i-need-help-understanding-a-proof-regarding-a-continuous-variable?rq=1

Comment: does this help you: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3570680/238708

Comment: Thank you very much i will check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume for the moment that $f_Y(y)\equiv0$ when $y\notin[0,N]$. Then your question is about the chain of  equations
$$\int_0^N\left(\int_y^N f_Y(x)\>dx\right)\>dy=\int_0^N\left(\int_0^x f_Y(x)\>dy\right)\>dx=\int_0^Nx\,f_Y(x)\>dx\ .$$
Only the first equality sign needs an explanation. We are integrating here over the right triangle $T$ with vertices $(0,0)$, $(N,0)$, $(N,N)$ in the $(x,y)$-plane, first integrating along $x$ and then along $y$, then first integrating along $y$ and then along $x$. That these two ways lead to the same result is "Fubini's theorem".